# Nested forms for in rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have two entities, `Project` and `Domain`. `Project belongs_to Domain` and `Domain has_many Projects`. So I populate the form from my `project index view`, and if I don't add
`accepts_nested_attributes_for :domain` in `project.rb` I can see the text-field, if I do add that line, the text-field disappears.

Also I get this in my log files: `Unpermitted parameters: domain`.

Project Controller:

```
 def create
   @domain = params[:domain][:name]
   @domain = Domain.find_or_create_by(name: @domain)
   @project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)
   @project.domain_id = @domain.id
   if @project.save
   end
 end

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :user_id, domain_attributes: [:name])
end
```

View

```
 <%=simple_form_for @project do |f|%>
   <%= f.input :name, label: 'Project name:'%>
   <%= f.simple_fields_for :domain do |d|%>
      <%= d.input :name, label: 'Domain name:', placeholder: 'domain.co.uk'%>
   <%end%>
   <%=f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success btn-sm'%>
  <%end%>
```

I get this only if I don't add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :domain`

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "project"=>{"name"=>"test", "domain"=>{"name"=>"test123.com"}}, "commit"=>"Create Project"}

It is important to have my `domain_id` in the `projects`. What can I do to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a domain so that there is an object to be used in `fields_for :domain` in your new action:

```
def new
  @project = ...
  @project.build_domain
  ...
end
```

The `Unpermitted parameters: domain.` message in your log is because in your `project_params` method you don't allow a `:domain` parameters, but your form is sending one. It should be fine thought, it is just a warning.